# 2D numpy array where spacing between items is defined by a function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distribution

I need a list or 2-d array of integers between a minimum value and a maximum value, where the interval between the integers varies according to a distribution function inversely. In other words, at the maximum value of the distribution the density should be highest. In my case something like a Weibull probability density function with k parameter 1.5 would be nice. 
Output would look something like this:

```
>>> min = 1
>>> max = 500
>>> peak = 100
>>> n = 18
>>> myfunc(min, max, peak, n)
[1, 50, 75, 88, 94, 97, 98, 99, 100, 102, 106, 112, 135, 176, 230, 290, 360, 500]
```

I already tried one method using the `np.random.weibull()` function to populate a numpy array but this doesn't work out nicely enough; the randomization when producing a list of 20 items means that the spacing is not satisfactory. It would be much better to avoid generating random numbers from a distribution and instead do what I described above, controlling the spacing directly. 
Thank you.

Edit: I mention a Weibull distribution because it is asymmetric, but of course any similar distribution function that gives similar results is also OK and may be more suitable.

Edit2: So I want a numpy non-linear space!

Edit3: As I answered in one comment, I want to avoid random number generation so that the function output is identical each time it is run with the same input parameters.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doing what you described above" because you don't give the code for `myfunc` nor specify in what way certain spacings might be "unsatisfactory". My attempt below is the closest I could get to guessing what you mean.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort. By "what I described above" I simply meant my description of what the output should be. myfunc() is simply an imaginary function that produces the correct output.

Comment: Are you trying to parametrize your distribution with these nodes? For me it is still unclear what "nicely enough" or "unsatisfactory" means.

Comment: When you use random number generation then each time you run the function the list values are different. I want them to be identical each time. Also, for a small sample size you are not guaranteed an "even" spacing; what I would like is a spacing as if linear but scaled to a function. Please see my own answer, perhaps it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rather unelegant but simple solution to my own question. I simplified things by using a triangular distribution function. This is good because it is easy to specify a minimum and maximum value.  A function named "spacing()" provides a spacing amount from the x value according to a specified mathematical function. After incrementing through a while loop I add the Max value to the list so that the full range is present. I then convert to integers while converting to a numpy array.

The downside of this method is that I must manually specify a minimum and maximum step size. I would rather specify the length of the returned array!

```
import numpy as np
import math

Min = 1.0
Max = 500.0
peak = 100.0

minstep = 1.0
maxstep = 50.0


def spacing(x):
    # Triangle distribution:
    if x < peak:
        # Since we are calculating gradients I keep everything as floats for now. 
        grad = (minstep - maxstep)/(peak - Min)
        return grad*x + maxstep
    elif x == peak:
        return minstep
    else:
        grad = (maxstep-minstep)/(Max-peak)
        return grad*x + minstep

def myfunc(Min, Max, peak, minstep, maxstep):
    x = 1.0
    chosen = []
    while x < Max:
        space = spacing(x)
        chosen.append(x)
        x += space
    chosen.append(Max)

    # I cheat with the integers by casting the list to ints right at the end: 
    chosen = np.array(chosen, dtype = 'int')
    return chosen

print myfunc(1.0, 500.0, 100.0, 1.0, 50.0)
```

Output:

```
[  1  50  75  88  94  97  99 100 113 128 145 163 184 208 235 264 298 335  378 425 478 500]
```

Comment: You might be interested in the [Ziggurat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm) algorithm. The way you are generating your nodes is similar to the generation of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, this function should do what you're asking:

```
def weibullspaced(min, max, k, arrsize):
    wb = np.random.weibull(k, arrsize - 1)
    spaced = np.zeros((arrsize,))
    spaced[1:] = np.cumsum(wb)
    diff = max - min
    spaced *= diff / spaced[-1]
    return min + np.rint(spaced)
```

You can of course substitute in any distribution you want, but you said you wanted Weibull. Is that the function you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you that is a useful function, however my question mentions avoiding random number generation altogether. The resulting list should be identical each time the function is called with the same input arguments.

Comment: Actually, I don't see in the original post where you mentioned that the output should be non-random. It's still not clear to me what the spacing function is supposed to be. There is  `peak` parameter, for example, and it looks like in your output there's some clustering around 100, but the question is still unclear to me. Maybe backing up: Suppose I put in min of 0, max of 100, output array of 50, what's an acceptable output array, and what isn't? Are all values allowed for `peak`? Or does if have to be between min and max? And what constraint on the output do we get if peak = 1 or 20 or 450?

Comment: "It would be much better to avoid generating random numbers from a distribution [...]" OK perhaps I should have been more clear, sorry.